# UnderscoreJS with MomentJS does not filter the results of a dynamic array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, underscore.js, momentjs

I am trying to format the results of an array using descending dates but when I try to enter my string `receivedDataThree` that contains a json simply my function does not le my array and in the result returns only an empty array but if I use a populated array with static data the function works without no problem what could be causing it?

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "JSON",
  url: 'https://famagas-api.herokuapp.com/api/itapeCompanyNews',
  success: function(allResponseThree) {
    // Native Array
    var receivedDataThree = [];

    // Group Received JSON By Total Of Purchased
    for (var i = 0; i < allResponseThree.length; i++) {
      // Group Received JSON By Total Of Purchased
      var totalOfPurchased = allResponseThree[i].purchase_history;
      for (var x = 0; x < totalOfPurchased.length; x++) {
        // Declare Variables Containing Extend Details
        var purchasedProductNested = totalOfPurchased[x].purchasedProduct;
        var dateOfPurchased = totalOfPurchased[x].dateOfPurchased;
        var quantityOfPurchasedNested = totalOfPurchased[x].quantityPurchased;
        var totalOfPurchasedNested = totalOfPurchased[x].totalOfPurchased;
        var totalOfDiscountsPurchasedNested = totalOfPurchased[x].discountsToConsider;

        // Format The Money So That It Is Possible To Count
        totalOfPurchasedNested = totalOfPurchasedNested.replace(/\./g, "").replace(",", ".");
        totalOfDiscountsPurchasedNested = totalOfDiscountsPurchasedNested.replace(/\./g, "").replace(",", ".");

        // Final JSON Array Containing Extend Details
        var allResponseThreeWithExtendDetails = {
          product: purchasedProductNested,
          dateOfPurchased: dateOfPurchased,
          quantity: JSON.parse(quantityOfPurchasedNested),
          totalPurchased: JSON.parse(totalOfPurchasedNested),
          totalDiscounts: JSON.parse(totalOfDiscountsPurchasedNested)
        };

        // Push Group With Received JSON In Native Array
        receivedDataThree.push(allResponseThreeWithExtendDetails);
      }
    }

    // Set Locale For Moment JS
    moment.locale("pt-BR");

    // Get Today Date
    var todayDate = moment();
    todayDate = todayDate.subtract(0, "days");
    todayDate = todayDate.format("DD/MM/YYYY");

    // Filter Purchased By Date
    var timeCreated = '11/05/2018';
    var arrayOfObjects = [{
        date: "11/04/2018",
        name: "Michael"
      },
      {
        date: "11/04/2018",
        name: "Larry"
      },
      {
        date: "11/12/2014",
        name: "Dean"
      },
      {
        date: "03/01/2015",
        name: "Jennifer"
      }
    ];

    var sortDate = _.filter(arrayOfObjects, function(desc) {
      return moment(desc.date).isAfter(moment(todayDate).subtract(30, 'days'))
    });

    console.log(sortDate);
  });
})
```

Explaining in more detail, when I try to declare my array `receivedDataThree` along with the field `dateOfPurchased` in my data filtering function

```
var sortDate = _.filter(receivedDataThree, function(desc) {
  return moment(desc.dateOfPurchased).isAfter(moment(todayDate).subtract(30, 'days'))
});
```

Only this is returned to me:

```
elements.js:449 
[]
```

But if I move the array entries in my function to a static array the result is valid and functional..

```js
var arrayOfObjects = [{
    date: "11/04/2018",
    name: "Michael"
  },
  {
    date: "11/04/2018",
    name: "Larry"
  },
  {
    date: "11/12/2014",
    name: "Dean"
  },
  {
    date: "03/01/2015",
    name: "Jennifer"
  }
];

var sortDate = _.filter(arrayOfObjects, function(desc) {
  return moment(desc.date).isAfter(moment(todayDate).subtract(30, 'days'))
});

console.log(sortDate);
```

Result with static array

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
{date: "11/04/2018", name: "Michael"}
{date: "11/04/2018", name: "Larry"}
```

Could help me with that? I thought it was some mistake to push the data from my ajax response to array but that's not it so I do not have the slightest idea how to solve this and I would be very grateful for anyone who helps me...

Thanks ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should solve the problem, I think the main problem was not passing the date format to the moment.js constructor.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "JSON",
  url: 'https://famagas-api.herokuapp.com/api/itapeCompanyNews',
  success: function(allResponseThree) {
    // Native Array
    var receivedDataThree = [];

    // Group Received JSON By Total Of Purchased
    for (var i = 0; i < allResponseThree.length; i++) {
      // Group Received JSON By Total Of Purchased
      var totalOfPurchased = allResponseThree[i].purchase_history;
      for (var x = 0; x < totalOfPurchased.length; x++) {
        // Declare Variables Containing Extend Details
        var purchasedProductNested = totalOfPurchased[x].purchasedProduct;
        var dateOfPurchased = totalOfPurchased[x].dateOfPurchased;
        var quantityOfPurchasedNested = totalOfPurchased[x].quantityPurchased;
        var totalOfPurchasedNested = totalOfPurchased[x].totalOfPurchased;
        var totalOfDiscountsPurchasedNested = totalOfPurchased[x].discountsToConsider;

        // Format The Money So That It Is Possible To Count
        totalOfPurchasedNested = totalOfPurchasedNested.replace(/\./g, "").replace(",", ".");
        totalOfDiscountsPurchasedNested = totalOfDiscountsPurchasedNested.replace(/\./g, "").replace(",", ".");

        // Final JSON Array Containing Extend Details
        var allResponseThreeWithExtendDetails = {
          product: purchasedProductNested,
          dateOfPurchased: dateOfPurchased,
          quantity: JSON.parse(quantityOfPurchasedNested),
          totalPurchased: JSON.parse(totalOfPurchasedNested),
          totalDiscounts: JSON.parse(totalOfDiscountsPurchasedNested)
        };

        // Push Group With Received JSON In Native Array
        receivedDataThree.push(allResponseThreeWithExtendDetails);
      }
    }

    // Set Locale For Moment JS
    moment.locale("pt-BR");
    var todayDate = moment();

    var sortDate = _.filter(receivedDataThree, function(desc) {
      return moment(desc.dateOfPurchased, "DD/MM/YYYY").isAfter(todayDate.subtract(30, 'days'))
    });

    console.log('Original data: ', receivedDataThree);
    console.log('Filtered data: ', sortDate);
  }
});
```

It's only the last lines I've changed. The main difference is we're passing the date format to moment.js in the moment(..) constructor.
e.g.

```
moment(desc.dateOfPurchased, "DD/MM/YYYY");
```

Here's a JS Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/6rqe6hpg/1/

Comment: Yess did you use debug?